# How to handle exception outside of page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, types

I have a C# project and I am trying to convert it to ASP.NET and C#. This is my first ASP.NET project.

My users have really liked my former project because it is flexible and easy to use. I am trying to duplicate it as much as possible.

I have designed a page called DM_Services.aspx with 3 panels:

- Panel 1 has a search button and several fields for filtering
- Panel 2 has several fields for editing
- Panel 3 has a gridview.

The ultimate goal is that the user can enter the filters and click search to load data in the gridview.

The user can click on a row in the gridview and it will load the fields in panel 2 with the data for viewing and editing.

I have a C# file called `SQLControl.cs` which I am using to manage data access.

I keep getting an error on that page in the `HasException` section.

If I use the following line:

```
ClientScriptManager.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(Me.GetType(), "ConfirmSubmit", exception);
```

I get the following error:

> The name 'Me' does not exist in the current context

If I use:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert(exception);", true);
```

I get the error:

> 'Page' is a type which does not exist in the current context

If I use the following line:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(This, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"), "alert(exception);", true);
```

I get this error:

> The name 'This' does not exist in the current context

And if I use:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"), "alert(exception);", true);
```

Then I get this error:

> Argument 1: cannot convertfrom 'Productivity_ASPWeb.SQLControl' to 'System.Web.UI.Control'

I am pretty sure I am getting this error because it is in `SQLControl.cs` which is outside of the page.

So how do I handle the exception then?

```
    public bool HasException(bool Report = false)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(exception))
            return false;

        if (Report == true) 
            ClientScriptManager.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(Me.GetType(), "ConfirmSubmit", exception);

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert(exception);", true);
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"), "alert(exception);", true);
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(This, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"), "alert(exception);", true);

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: By `Me.GetType()` are you using `Me` in the Visual Basic sense (the current instance of the class you are in)?  If so, the C# equivalent of `Me` is `this`.  You could say `this.GetType()` or simply `GetType()`.  What you need to do is get the instance of the page that has called into your class and use it.  Does the page create an instance of your `SQLControl` class?  If so, initialize it with the page instance and use that page instance in your code

Comment: DM_Services has the following line: public SQLControl SQL = new SQLControl();

Comment: Change your `SQLControl` constructor to take a `Page` in as a parameter.  Store it privately within your SQLControl class.  Use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the scriptManager from the SQLControl.cs and changed the code to:

```
        public bool HasException(bool Report = false)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(exception))
            return false;
        else
        return true;
    }
```

I then put the scriptmanager in the aspx page:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert(exception);", true);
    }
```